# How to share Google Drive file from Android app?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

My Android app creating a file on Google Drive using new Google Drive API. I'm getting DriveFile object successfully.

The question is: **how to share this file from my app?** Links to relevant topics and especially code samples are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android-specific API does not yet support sharing.  You can use the RESTful web API to do this. See [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions).

From a DriveId you can get the resourceId, which is the id you need in order to access a file in the web API.

Comment: Thanks, Cheryl, this approach solved the issue. Should admit Drive API regarding permissions and communication between old and new APIs for Android it's not very clear and doesn't contain samples.

Comment: Actually, v1 of Google Drive SDK for Android supports permsissions: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert.

Comment: @Cheryl how and where to call this can you show a working example please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378746/how-to-insert-share-permission-to-a-file-in-google-drive-using-driveapi-in-andro

Comment: can anyone please help to understand, how to use this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Permission newPermission = new Permission();
newPermission.setValue(emailvalue);
newPermission.setType(type);
newPermission.setRole(role);
try {
   service.permissions().insert(fid, newPermission).execute();
   showToast("Done Shared successfully!!!!!!");
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
}
```

Comment: while calling this i called no permission and google oauth exception

Comment: just make sure that the file you are trying to change the permission, you have correct that permission on that file. owner of the file

Comment: i get unauthorized acess while trying to call this.I think i am not correctly creating the token and all,how is that we use the oauth token

Comment: I am getting this error - `cannot resolve method 'insert(java.lang.String, com.google.api.services.drive.model.Permission)'`